# React get a Button's id in

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass the ID of a button, when it's clicked, to a function but I've been unable to get anything to happen. I'm going to put some logic into the function that will change the font size based on if the user hits "increaseButton" or "decreaseButton" which is easy enough, but I'm having trouble being able to get the id for the buttons.
**Component**

```
fontSize(e) {
      console.log(e.target.id);
 }
```

**Render**

```
 <button id="decreaseButton"  hidden={isHidden} onClick {this.fontSize.bind(this)}>-</button>
```

Comment: it should work check the [**working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/c9rmfk9z/).

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned, you are going to change font size based on `increase` or `decrease` actions. Why don't you use both buttons and bind them with their specific actions so you don't have to rely on attributes of any kind?

```js
const Button = ({ children, onClick }) => <button onClick={onClick}>{children}</button>

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      fontSize: 16,
    }

    this.handleDecrease = this.handleDecrease.bind(this)
    this.handleIncrease = this.handleIncrease.bind(this)
  }

  handleDecrease() {
    // Sample rule: fontSize should no be less than 10
    this.setState({ fontSize: Math.max(this.state.fontSize - 1, 10) })
  }
  
  handleIncrease() {
    // Sample rule: fontSize should not be greater than 30
    this.setState({ fontSize: Math.min(this.state.fontSize + 1, 30) })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.handleDecrease}>
          Decrease font
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={this.handleIncrease}>
          Increase font
        </Button>
        
        <div>Current fontSize: {this.state.fontSize}</div>
        <div style={{ fontSize: this.state.fontSize }}>Preview</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Essentially, this is what I did, however, I was just wondering if there was a way to do this in React without creating two separate functions, I thought it would be tidier but if that's not best practice please let me know.  Obviously, it wouldn't make a difference for something of this size but if it was a larger project, perhaps?

Comment: What you mean? Create separate functions/components is not a best practice? If that's the case, you are wrong. Using buttons separately reduce business logic, increases reusability among other components and makes tests even easier.

Comment: In case you want to remove the `Button` component I created, simply use `<button onClick={this.handleDecrease}>Decrease</button>` and you are good to go :)